# How to use SmallCheck in Haskell?

Tags: testing, haskell, automated-tests, monads, smallcheck

I am trying to use [SmallCheck](https://github.com/feuerbach/smallcheck) to test a Haskell program, but I cannot understand how to use the library to test my own data types. Apparently, I need to use the [Test.SmallCheck.Series](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/smallcheck/1.0.2/doc/html/Test-SmallCheck-Series.html). However, I find the documentation for it extremely confusing.  I am interested in both cookbook-style solutions and an understandable explanation of the logical (monadic?) structure. Here are some questions I have (all related):

- If I have a data type `data Person = SnowWhite | Dwarf Integer`, how do I explain to `smallCheck` that the valid values are `Dwarf 1` through `Dwarf 7` (or `SnowWhite`)? What if I have a complicated `FairyTale` data structure and a constructor `makeTale :: [Person] -> FairyTale`, and I want `smallCheck` to make FairyTale-s from lists of Person-s using the constructor?

  I managed to make  `quickCheck` work like this without getting my hands too dirty by using judicious applications of `Control.Monad.liftM` to functions like `makeTale`. I couldn't figure out a way to do this with `smallCheck` (please explain it to me!).
- What is the relationship between the types `Serial`, `Series`, etc.?
- (optional) What is the point of `coSeries`? How do I use the `Positive` type from `SmallCheck.Series`?
- (optional) Any elucidation of what is the logic behind what should be a monadic expression, and what is just a regular function, in the context of smallCheck, would be appreciated.

If there is there any intro/tutorial to using `smallCheck`, I'd appreciate a link. Thank you very much!

**UPDATE:** I should add that the most useful and readable documentation I found for `smallCheck` is [this paper (PDF)](http://www.cs.york.ac.uk/fp/smallcheck/smallcheck.pdf). I could not find the answer to my questions there on the first look; it is more of a persuasive advertisement than a tutorial.

**UPDATE 2:** I moved my question about the weird `Identity` that shows up in the type of `Test.SmallCheck.list` and other places to a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557610/why-does-smallchecks-series-class-have-two-types-in-the-constructor-what-is).

Answer (score 17):

**NOTE:** This answer describes pre-1.0 versions of SmallCheck. See [this blog post](http://ro-che.info/articles/2013-02-19-smallcheck.html) for the important differences between SmallCheck 0.6 and 1.0.

SmallCheck is like QuickCheck in that it tests a property over some part of the space of possible types. The difference is that it tries to exhaustively enumerate a series *all* of the "small" values instead of an arbitrary subset of smallish values.

As I hinted, SmallCheck's `Serial` is like QuickCheck's `Arbitrary`.

Now `Serial` is pretty simple: a `Serial` type `a` has a way (`series`) to generate a `Series` type which is just a function from `Depth -> [a]`. Or, to unpack that, `Serial` objects are objects we know how to enumerate some "small" values of. We are also given a `Depth` parameter which controls how many small values we should generate, but let's ignore it for a minute.

```
instance Serial Bool where series _ = [False, True]
instance Serial Char where series _ = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
instance Serial a => Serial (Maybe a) where
  series d = Nothing : map Just (series d)
```

In these cases we're doing nothing more than ignoring the `Depth` parameter and then enumerating "all" possible values for each type. We can even do this automatically for some types

```
instance (Enum a, Bounded a) => Serial a where series _ = [minBound .. maxBound]
```

This is a really simple way of testing properties exhaustively—literally test every single possible input! Obviously there are at least two major pitfalls, though: (1) infinite data types will lead to infinite loops when testing and (2) nested types lead to exponentially larger spaces of examples to look through. In both cases, SmallCheck gets really large really quickly.

So that's the point of the `Depth` parameter—it lets the system ask us to keep our `Series` small. From the documentation, `Depth` is the

> Maximum depth of generated test values
>
> For data values, it is the depth of nested constructor applications.
>
> For functional values, it is both the depth of nested case analysis and the depth of results.

so let's rework our examples to keep them Small.

```
instance Serial Bool where 
  series 0 = []
  series 1 = [False]
  series _ = [False, True]
instance Serial Char where 
  series d = take d "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
instance Serial a => Serial (Maybe a) where
  -- we shrink d by one since we're adding Nothing
  series d = Nothing : map Just (series (d-1))

instance (Enum a, Bounded a) => Serial a where series d = take d [minBound .. maxBound]
```

Much better.

---

So what's `coseries`? Like `coarbitrary` in the `Arbitrary` typeclass of QuickCheck, it lets us build a series of "small" functions. Note that we're writing the instance over the input type---the result type is handed to us in another `Serial` argument (that I'm below calling `results`).

```
instance Serial Bool where
  coseries results d = [\cond -> if cond then r1 else r2 | 
                        r1 <- results d
                        r2 <- results d]
```

these take a little more ingenuity to write and I'll actually refer you to use the `alts` methods which I'll describe briefly below.

---

So how can we make some `Series` of `Person`s? This part is easy

```
instance Series Person where
  series           d = SnowWhite : take (d-1) (map Dwarf [1..7])
  ...
```

But our `coseries` function needs to generate every possible function from `Person`s to something else. This can be done using the `altsN` series of functions provided by SmallCheck. Here's one way to write it

```
 coseries results d = [\person -> 
                         case person of
                           SnowWhite -> f 0
                           Dwarf n   -> f n
                       | f <- alts1 results d ]
```

The basic idea is that `altsN results` generates a `Series` of `N`-ary function from `N` values with `Serial` instances to the `Serial` instance of `Results`. So we use it to create a function from [0..7], a previously defined `Serial` value, to whatever we need, then we map our `Person`s to numbers and pass 'em in.

---

So now that we have a `Serial` instance for `Person`, we can use it to build more complex nested `Serial` instances. For "instance", if `FairyTale` is a list of `Person`s, we can use the `Serial a => Serial [a]` instance alongside our `Serial Person` instance to easily create a `Serial FairyTale`:

```
instance Serial FairyTale where
  series = map makeFairyTale . series
  coseries results = map (makeFairyTale .) . coseries results
```

(the `(makeFairyTale .)` composes `makeFairyTale` with each function `coseries` generates, which is a little confusing)

Comment: Dear tel, Thank you for your answer. I appreciate the concreteness; it is very elucidating that `Series a` is just `Depth -> [a]`. One more question confuses me: *why is the type of `SmallCheck.Series.list` so strange?* Should I just ignore the `Identity` when I use it?

Comment: Er - actually I'm having some **problems**. I'm trying to compile the `SnowWhite` example (i.e. make `Person` an instance of `Serial`). I'm getting an error about a "Kind mis-match"; apparently the argument of `Serial` should have kind `* -> *` but `Person` has kind `*`. I don't know how to fix this. Also, it does not seem to be true that `Series` is just `Depth -> [a]` according to doing `:i Series` in ghc (though it's very helpful that I know what it morally should be). Perhaps your explanation is only valid for an older version? Thank you!

Comment: I have partially figured out the above-mentioned problem. Please see the "answer" I wrote and the other question linked from it, if you are interested. Thank you again, very much, I now understand everything much better. In a reasonable world, your answer would be correct on the nose. On the other hand, I'm sure someone will explain to me what benefit `smallCheck` gains from all the extra-confusion in its design.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't actually test all the code. It's got many errors. I can't fix them on my phone right now: I will later.

Comment: Oh—and I'm not running a modern version of smallcheck! Sorry, I'll look into that as well.

Comment: These examples are based off of Smallcheck 0.6. As of the newest version, version 1.0.2, the `Series` has changed from `Depth -> [a]` to an instance of `MonadLogic`. Monad logic is basically a list with some monadic effects snuck in between the layers (it's one possible version of a non-broken `ListT` transformer). In this new version it's highly recommended to use the `consN` constructors, which are similar to the `altsN` constructors, to build your `Serial` instances.

Answer (score 4):

- If I have a data type `data Person = SnowWhite | Dwarf Integer`, how do I explain to `smallCheck` that the valid values are `Dwarf 1` through `Dwarf 7` (or `SnowWhite`)?

First of all, you need to decide which values you want to generate for each depth. There's no single right answer here, it depends on how fine-grained you want your search space to be.

Here are just two possible options:

1. `people d = SnowWhite : map Dwarf [1..7]` (doesn't depend on the depth)
2. `people d = take d $ SnowWhite : map Dwarf [1..7]` (each unit of depth increases the search space by one element)

After you've decided on that, your `Serial` instance is as simple as

```
instance Serial m Person where
    series = generate people
```

We left `m` polymorphic here as we don't require any specific structure of the underlying monad.

- What if I have a complicated `FairyTale` data structure and a constructor `makeTale :: [Person] -> FairyTale`, and I want `smallCheck` to make FairyTale-s from lists of Person-s using the constructor?

Use `cons1`:

```
instance Serial m FairyTale where
  series = cons1 makeTale
```

- What is the relationship between the types `Serial`, `Series`, etc.?

`Serial` is a type class; `Series` is a type. You can have multiple `Series` of the same type — they correspond to different ways to enumerate values of that type. However, it may be arduous to specify for each value how it should be generated. The `Serial` class lets us specify a good default for generating values of a particular type.

The definition of `Serial` is

```
class Monad m => Serial m a where
  series   :: Series m a
```

So all it does is assigning a particular `Series m a` to a given combination of `m` and `a`.

- What is the point of `coseries`?

It is needed to generate values of functional types.

- How do I use the `Positive` type from `SmallCheck.Series`?

For example, like this:

```
> smallCheck 10 $ \n -> n^3 >= (n :: Integer)
Failed test no. 5.
there exists -2 such that
  condition is false

> smallCheck 10 $ \(Positive n) -> n^3 >= (n :: Integer)
Completed 10 tests without failure.
```

- Any elucidation of what is the logic behind what should be a monadic expression, and what is just a regular function, in the context of smallCheck, would be appreciated.

When you are writing a `Serial` instance (or any `Series` expression), you work in the `Series m` monad.

When you are writing tests, you work with simple functions that return `Bool` or `Property m`.

Answer (score 1):

While I think that @tel's answer is an excellent explanation (and I wish `smallCheck` actually worked the way he describes), the code he provides does not work for me (with `smallCheck` version 1). I managed to get the following to work...

> **UPDATE / WARNING:** The code below **is wrong** for a rather subtle reason. For the corrected version, and details, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16560092/563359) to the question mentioned below. The short version is that instead of `instance Serial Identity Person` one must write `instance (Monad m) => Series m Person`.

... but I find the use of `Control.Monad.Identity` and all the compiler flags bizarre, and I have asked a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557610/why-does-smallchecks-series-class-have-two-types-in-the-constructor-what-is) about that.

Note also that while `Series Person` (or actually `Series Identity Person`) is not actually exactly the same as functions `Depth -> [Person]` (see @tel's answer), the function `generate :: Depth -> [a] -> Series m a` converts between them.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}
import Test.SmallCheck
import Test.SmallCheck.Series
import Control.Monad.Identity

data Person = SnowWhite | Dwarf Int

instance Serial Identity Person where
        series = generate (\d -> SnowWhite : take (d-1) (map Dwarf [1..7]))
```